# instance of type cannot be tracked because of another instance with same ID error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, invalidoperationexception

I have a .net core 2.1 mvc application with EF Core where I use automapper to match viewmodels with domainmodels. In my edit method I get the error :

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'Ticket' cannot be tracked because another instance with the
>   same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked.

The several other topics here did not solve my problem.

My Edit method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, TicketViewModel ticketViewModel)
    {
    Ticket ticketToUpdate = await _unitOfWork.Ticket.Get(id); // I implement unit of work 

    // some logic for checks
    // ...

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // mapping  Ticket viewmodel to Ticket Domain Model
                ticketViewModel = _mapper.Map<TicketViewModel>(ticketToUpdate);

                // update some properties on viewmodel

                _mapper.Map(ticketViewModel, ticketToUpdate); // doesn't map values.

                _unitOfWork.Ticket.Update(ticketToUpdate); //No longer fails
                await _unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

My mapping:

```
CreateMap<TicketViewModel, Ticket>()
.ForMember(x => x.ID, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Ticket.ID))
.ForMember(x => x.Title, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Ticket.Title))
.ForMember(x => x.Description, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Ticket.Description))


CreateMap<Ticket, TicketViewModel>()
.ForPath(x => x.Ticket.ID, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.ID))
.ForPath(x => x.Ticket.Title, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Title))
.ForPath(x => x.Ticket.Description, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Description))
```

EDIT: The InvalidOperationException is now solved, but the final mapping doesn't seem to map the values of the viewmodel to the _dbcontext entity.

Comment: Is `_unitOfWork` injected via DI? How you instantiate _unitOfWork?

Comment: `_unitOfWork.Ticket.Get(id)` returns one instance of the ticket with the given Id, and `_mapper.Map<TopdeskChanges>(ticketViewModel)` returns another instance, which you then pass to `_unitOfWork.Ticket.Update(x)`. Now you have two instances with the same Id, as the exception indicates. Which "several other topics" did you read, what advice did you implement and how did that not work? If you only retrieve it by Id to check whether it exists, and maybe if the current user is allowed to update it, load it as not being tracked.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yes, both automapper and unitofwork are injected using DI.

Comment: But beware that pushing a POSTed, mapped entity as update to your ORM, you allow the user to modify any field.

Comment: @CodeCaster some ref's I found pointed to the AsNoTracking attribute. Others referred to modelbuilder in domainmapping. Unfortunately, it is not sufficient just to see if a posted ticket already exists, I need to perform some business logic on the retrieved record's fields before I update it to the db.

Comment: Yeah sure, but reading can be performed without tracking the entity. And that would solve that problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thnx, I removed the first _unitOfWork.Ticket.Get(id) and indeed now the mapping works. However, all the properties that are not in the viewmodel, are not retained and set to null, which is undesired.How can I use automapper with that specific record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are loading the domain item, however you are using the wrong automapper call:

```
ticketToUpdate = _mapper.Map<Ticket>(ticketViewModel);
```

This should be:

```
_mapper.Map(ticketViewModel, ticketToUpdate);
```

The first method takes the values from the view model and loads them into a brand new instance of the Entity and assigns it to the ticketToUpdate reference previously loaded. When you go to update that reference, the dbContext behind your unit of work is already tracking the entity with the same ID so you get the error. (The updated reference is treated as a new entity)

The second `Map` call example copies the values from the ViewModel over into the entity referenced by the ticketToUpdate. The resulting reference is pointing at the original entity which gets the new values, and the DbContext will save those changes.

** Edit: A simple test to outline the behaviour difference with the Map call. If the `Map(source, destination)` call is not copying over the values you expect, check your mappings to ensure the 2-way conversion is correct.

```
[Test]
public void TestCopyOver()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
            .ForMember(x => x.MyName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Name))
            .ForMember(x => x.MyOtherName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.OtherName));
        cfg.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassA>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.MyName))
            .ForMember(x => x.OtherName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.MyOtherName));
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    ClassA newA = new ClassA { Name = "Fred", OtherName = "Astaire" };
    ClassA altReferenceA = newA;
    Assert.AreSame(newA, altReferenceA, "References don't match.");
    var cloneB = mapper.Map<ClassB>(newA);
    cloneB.MyOtherName = "Rogers";

    newA = mapper.Map<ClassA>(cloneB);
    Assert.AreEqual("Rogers", newA.OtherName);
    Assert.AreEqual("Astaire", altReferenceA.OtherName); // original object not updated.
    Assert.AreNotSame(newA, altReferenceA); // now point to 2 different objects

    //Reset...

    newA = new ClassA { Name = "Fred", OtherName = "Astaire" };
    altReferenceA = newA;
    Assert.AreSame(newA, altReferenceA, "References don't match.");
    cloneB = mapper.Map<ClassB>(newA);
    cloneB.MyOtherName = "Rogers";

    mapper.Map(cloneB, newA);
    Assert.AreEqual("Rogers", newA.OtherName);
    Assert.AreEqual("Rogers", altReferenceA.OtherName); // Original object updated.
    Assert.AreSame(newA, altReferenceA); // Still point to same reference.
}
```

Here the "newA" represents a reference to an entity pulled from a dbContext. We take a 2nd reference to that same entity to compare later. (altReferenceA). If we call `newA = mapper.Map<ClassA>(cloneB)` it is now a new reference and this results in the exception with EF. EF is tracking the entity still pointed to by altReferenceA. newA is treated as a new, untracked entity.

In the second pass we reset the variables and using `mapper.Map(cloneB, newA)` we copy the value from B to A, both references are updated since they still point to the same object. The tracked entity is updated and can be saved.  If the values from B do not get written to newA then I would suspect something is wrong with the mapping configuration from B to A. If the values are being updated in the entity but the entity is not persisting the changes, then I would look at what the `Commit()` method in your unit of work is trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: The two models seem to map, or at least the code is passed without errors, but the values are not overwritten and the original values are retained.

Comment: It certainly should work. I've added a base example that I've just run to outline the difference between the two mapper calls. If your code isn't updating the entity with the `.Map(source, destination)` call then check your mapping configuration. What version of Automapper are you using? My test was with v8 and v9.

Comment: I'm still unable to get this to work. I use AutoMapper 6.0, but I don't think that's the problem. I'm confused about your intermediary mapping: `cloneB = mapper.Map<ClassB>(newA);` I assume that `cloneB` is my viewmodel, but when I do this, the values are overwritten with the values from the `_dbcontext`, which is also how I read that line of code: Assign the values to cloneB. It seems redundant, and leading to the same result as the line below it: `mapper.Map(cloneB, newA);`. I have updated my code.

Comment: cloneB was just the proxy I had for a view model, which I clone from the model to get the initial values. Your mappings look a little funny with the entity. Why does it look like a "Ticket" contains a "Ticket"? I.e. `.ForMember(x => x.ID, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Ticket.ID))`. `y` in the MapFrom should reflect a Ticket entity, so I'd expect `y.ID` rather than `y.Ticket.ID`..

Comment: thank you for your elaboration and time. I got it to work. The error was in the mapping. After I changed that, the mapping worked as planned. I will update my code soon with the solution.