# How to update data in entity framework using automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I have this code but I can't get it to work together, if I comment the first 4 lines of code if I update the address,and if I comment on the code to update the address, it no longer updates the  ClienteTipodeConcepto.

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Cliente cliente)
{

    var clienteDB = await context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId);
    if (clienteDB == null) { return NotFound(); }
    clienteDB = mapper.Map(cliente, clienteDB);
    clienteDB.ClienteTipodeConcepto = cliente.ClienteTipodeConcepto;

    context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (var direccion in cliente.Direccion)
    {
        if (direccion.DireccionId != null)
        {
            context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    var listadoDireccionesIds = cliente.Direccion.Select(x => x.DireccionId).ToList();
    var direccionesABorrar = await context
        .Direcciones
        .Where(x => !listadoDireccionesIds.Contains(x.DireccionId) && x.Cliente.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId)
        .ToListAsync();
    context.RemoveRange(direccionesABorrar);           

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

this part:

```
  var clienteDB = await context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId);
    if (clienteDB == null) { return NotFound(); }
    clienteDB = mapper.Map(cliente, clienteDB);
    clienteDB.ClienteTipodeConcepto = cliente.ClienteTipodeConcepto;
```

no longer allows me to update what is below:

```
 context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (var direccion in cliente.Direccion)
    {
        if (direccion.DireccionId != null)
        {
            context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }
```

error:

> Error AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
> Mapping types: Cliente -> Cliente BlazorApp.Shared.Models.Cliente ->
> BlazorApp.Shared.Models.Cliente Type Map configuration: Cliente ->
> Cliente BlazorApp.Shared.Models.Cliente ->
> BlazorApp.Shared.Models.Cliente Destination Member:
> ClienteTipodeConcepto ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The
> instance of entity type 'Direccion' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'DireccionId'} is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using

How can I make the whole form update fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862416/instance-of-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-of-another-instance-with-same-id-erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have and entity tracked by the context (found by matching ClienteId):

```
var clienteDB = await context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId);
```

This statement updates the tracked entity with `cliente` (this would set `clienteDB` state to `EntityState.Modified`):

```
clienteDB = mapper.Map(cliente, clienteDB);
```

Then you try to get the context to track the original item `cliente` with the same Id in the context.

```
context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You cannot have two instances tracking the same entity. I would remove this line and adjust the rest of your code to work with `clienteDB`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you just need to convert the object that you are passing as an input to the corresponding object model declared in `dbcontext`:

```cs
var clienteDB = mapper.Map<object model declared in ef>(cliente);
```

Then if you want to have a control if this record already exists:

```cs
var clienteDB = await context.Clientes.FindAsync(cliente.ClienteId);
    if (clienteDB == null) { return NotFound(); }
```

and then iterate each element from the object corresponding to the context:

```cs
context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach (var direccion in clienteDB.Direccion)
{
    if (direccion.DireccionId != null)
    {
        context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(direccion).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a map error if I only pass the cliente, map expects the source and destination

Comment: yes but the automapper it's generic so you can set it mapper.map<Your object model in dbcontext>(cliente)

Comment: @Enrique, it seems here one could also use context.Clients.Update(cliente) instead.